# VB .NET DataGridView SQL Order List

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net

I am just wondering if someone would be willing to give me some advice.

I have a DataGridView which contains data pulled from my SQL Database. I am wanting to find out how I can reorder the rows within the DataGridView.

Currently I am using a rank system. I have a field called ListOrder in my database which represents the rank of what order it is displayed in my DGV and I am using ORDER BY ListOrder to display it in the correct sequence.

Everytime a new record is added to the database, I use a count query and then + 1 to the new record. So for example if I have 10 records in my table, it counts 10 and then adds + 1 so it would equal to 11 for the new record. The problem with this is that if I have deleted records in the table, the rank becomes incorrect. Another example is that I delete the first record which leaves 9 in my table, but because I am using count, it would count 9 in the table then add the + 1, which gives it a value of 10, which means I could have 2 records in the database containing my ListOrder of 10. (hope that makes sense) I understand I can use the MAX query also, but this still gives me a similar problem.

When I delete a record, I need it to recount all the records and leave them in the same order.

Below is the code I am using to move my records up and down within the table:

```
v_SelectRow = dgvLine1.CurrentRow.Index
dbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\planner.mdb;")
dbConnection.Open()

strSQL = "UPDATE [Line1Orders] SET [ListOrder] = ListOrder-1  WHERE ([DateTime] = '" & dgvLine1.Item(8, v_SelectRow).Value & "')"

dbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, dbConnection)
dbCount = dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery
dbConnection.Close()
```

The other problem I am having due to the count query is that when I delete records for example  4,5,6 out of my table, the next record which has a ListOrder value of 7 needs to be moved up 3 times before it will go past the record before it.

I hope this makes sense. I would really appreciate it if someone would be willing to point me in the right direction to what functions, queries and any logical idea to how I can improve this current system. I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Ahh! Sql Injection alert! Don't use string concatenation to substitute values into queries like that. _Ever._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an autoincrementing primary key to your data table. Add an order by clause to your SQL to order by the primary key you just added.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiousity - why do the numbers need to be consistent? Couldn't you keep a counter incrementing and then when you display it to the user display a counter that you create at that time.

You have records 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 10, 15
Next record you insert would be 16.
When you display the records to the user, display 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

Do you really need to display the actual rank to the customer? Is that number important to them.